# Porque no puedo colocar i después del index | Why can't I use i as argument of index

Tags: ruby

La idea es desemcriptar message, ya esta la logica pero no puedo poner la i después del index dentro del for

<sub>**translation:** *The goal is to decipher the message; I've already written the logic but I can't use `i` as argument of `index` in the `for` loop.*</sub>

```
message = "rvtufkmbrdpr fmasmegppreemvemeuaiv tmgb"
messageArray = message.chars
decrypted = ""
alphabet = ["","a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"]
for i in(messageArray)
    letter = ""
    letter = alphabet[((alphabet.index(i))+14)%27]
    decrypted = decrypted + letter
end
puts decrypted
```

Comment: [Stack Overflow is English-only](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/262054/567762), sorry!

Comment: I think you are looking for [Stack Overflow en español](https://es.stackoverflow.com).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The issue isn't that you can't use `i` in `Enumerable#index` but that your alphabet needs to include a space `" "` instead of the empty string `""`.

```rb
message = "rvtufkmbrdpr fmasmegppreemvemeuaiv tmgb"
alphabet = " abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".chars #=> [" ", "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"]

message.chars.each_with_object("") do |char,decrypted|
  decrypted << alphabet[ (alphabet.index(char)+14)%alphabet.size ]
end
```

```rb
#=> "eighty percent of success is showing up"
```